# How to update CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services

`yum --v update` on a Fresh install of CentOS 8 at AWS, I get:

`Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist`

A bit of reading shows that CentOS 8 appears to becoming CentOS Stream 8, and all the mirrors are showing that the product is end-of-life: http://mirror.centos.org/centos-8/8/readme

If I open up `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-AppStream.repo` the url referenced there resolves to: http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=ec2
and that appears to be the cause of the issue above. As it says

'Invalid release/repo/arch combination'

What to do? Is CentOS 7  my only option. I cant find any "CentOS Stream 8" images in AWS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CentOS 7 - end of life in 2024, then what](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080911/centos-7-end-of-life-in-2024-then-what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should be http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8-stream&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=ec2, specifically with `8-stream` as the release.

There's some other instructions on swapping from non-stream to stream on the official pages here: https://www.centos.org/centos-stream/

Also note that if you're using AWS, then you may want to make use of building AMIs to provide stable images to your environment based on stream. It's easy enough to set up a pipeline to build a base image each week that can then be used for testing and deployment. This can mitigate some of the 'risk' with using a stream-based release.

Comment: I did ```echo '8-stream' > /etc/yum/vars/releasever``` and ran update agin, it's busy updating now.

Comment: I see Google Cloud Platform use something called 'CentOS Linux 8'

Comment: So do AWS on the marketplace. Just search Centos 8 and there's one published by AWS.

Comment: I tried Yesterday (1st Feb 2022) on the Google Cloud Platform their CentOS 8 (not Stream) no longer updates out the box. It worked just a few days ago, but not now. I was only able to use CentOS 8 Stream from GCP out the box without changing out the repos